# What is 'react-hot-loader/babel' for?

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

I have setup react-hot-reload based on the [getting started](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hot-loader) on npm. The first step was to add

```
// .babelrc
{
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

I have a single component app with a counter state and button that increments the states counter. When testing this out it appears to work, and retain its state with/without this plugin in my `.babelrc` when I add/remove random components in my render() method.

So my question is, what is this peice of the jigsaw meant to be doing? why is it required?

The App i'm using to test this,

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value:0};
    }

    handleButtonClick(event)
    {
        console.log("click");
        this.setState( state => ({
            value:state.value + 44

        }));
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <div>
            <a>asd</a>
            <p>asssd</p>
        <input></input>
          <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}></button>
            2<div>{this.state.value}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default hot(App);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand? The link you posted tells you what its for, how it works, and how it's being deprecated by Fast Loader

Comment: Specifically the babel component. I understand what react-hot-reload is for. But as mentioned above, if I add or remove that bit in .babelrc I see no difference. I am still using the import in the App.js and using export default hot(App), just excluding the .babelrc plugin, and it still works. The URL I liked to doesn't explain what the babel bit is for specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the react-hot-reload/babel plugin is for quick development. It allows scripts that have recently been changed to be updated **without** the need to refresh the app/page. It is not required by any means, but allows developers to quickly iterate and view their code changes without losing state in memory.

Comment: Right, but testing without react-hot-reload/babel and I still don't loose my state with the above sample app. Clicking the button a few times, and then changing something in the .jsx file and the counter value remains the same, and the changes appear. The bit that seems to make this happen was the import in the jsx file and wrapping the App with hot() - so still unsure what this babel bit actually does.

Comment: Seconded. I removed `react-hot-loader/babel` from `.babelrc` and everything still hot-reloaded and retains state. Same with `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin` in the webpack config - doesn't seem to be needed.